# Show the full size of image on a header [CSS]

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm facing problem with showing the whole image on a header. I tried both contain and cover and nothing week, any help would be appreciated.Here is a screenshot of my problem and code. 
[image]

```
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  color:#464655;
  background-color: #E5E0CD;
  outline:none;}

a {text-decoration: none;}

h1{
    font-family:"SummerHearts-Regular";
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:16px;}

  #cd-intro {
  background: url(trees.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:block;
  background-size:100% 170px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;}

#cd-intro #cd-intro-tagline {
  width: auto;
  width:90%;
  position:relative;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;}

  @media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  #cd-intro {
    height: 170px; 
  }
  #cd-intro #cd-intro-tagline {
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
  #cd-intro input {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

.cd-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 1.8em;
  background-color:#D23C69;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #E5E0CD;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<header>
    <section id="cd-intro">
        <div id="cd-intro-tagline">
            <img src="C:\Users\Maryam\Desktop\TravelGeni\Trip\css\Travel Geni.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:110px;left:-80px;top:0;position:absolute;">

             <h1 style="top:0;">Edit Trip</h1>
             <a href="" class="cd-btn">Delete</a>
            <a href="" class="cd-btn">Mark Complete</a>


        </div> <!-- #cd-intro-tagline -->
    </section> <!-- #cd-intro -->
</header> 
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what I essentially want to have, like this picture. [image]

Comment: You have to explain that better, as I have no clue what you ask. Make the _how you want_ picture from your original instead, so it clearly shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you actually want and don't want, but here in your code:...

```
 background-size:100% 170px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

...the last line overwrites the first one: same parameter, different value -> later one overwrites earlier one

If your problem is the position of the "cover" backgroun, you might want to change something here:

```
background: url(trees.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

This `center center` is the position, so if you want your background image to be aligned top or bottom, change that second "center" (i.e. the vertical position) to "top" or "bottom", or also to a pixel value.

Comment: Thank you, so I want the full image to show on header, so now it only displays the beginning of the picture, not all of it.

Comment: Yes of course - you wouldn't want the height to be squeezed to 170 px but the picture to remain in proportion, would you? (please also note the edit of my question)

Comment: No, I just want it to fit the whole header, so in one word I want to squeeze the whole picture into the header.

Comment: then use `background-size: contain`, but this will result  in empty parts to the left and right on desktop screens. If you don't understand what I mean: Try `background-size: 100% 100%`: This will fit in the image perfectly, but it will distort the image and change its width/height proportion. BTW: Another way to get a different dimension is to change the height of the header element itself (not the background image)

Answer (score 1):

The image can be set as background and its background-size property can be set to cover.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  color: #464655;
  background-color: #E5E0CD;
  outline: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "SummerHearts-Regular";
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 16px;
}

#cd-intro {
  background: url(http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg) no-repeat;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-size: 100% 170px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#cd-intro #cd-intro-tagline {
  width: auto;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  #cd-intro {
    height: 170px;
  }
  #cd-intro #cd-intro-tagline {
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
  #cd-intro input {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

.cd-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 1.8em;
  background-color: #D23C69;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #E5E0CD;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <section id="cd-intro">
      <div id="cd-intro-tagline">
        <h1 style="top:0;">Edit Trip</h1>
        <a href="" class="cd-btn">Delete</a>
        <a href="" class="cd-btn">Mark Complete</a>
      </div>
      <!-- #cd-intro-tagline -->
    </section>
    <!-- #cd-intro -->
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for, appreciate your help, thanks again!